# Not able to understand "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS" date format

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I am trying to parse following date time string

**2018-01-30T23:59:59.000**

I am not able to understand which standard format it is like UTC or ISO_8601

while parsing in the following manner:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD'T'HH:MM:SS:MS");
        Date date = null;
        try {
            date = sdf.parse("2018-01-30T23:59:59.000");
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But It is throwing following exception:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2018-01-30T23:59:59.000"
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Your string is ISO 8601, and `LocalDateTime` from `java.time` will parse it without any explicit formatter, so you’ll have no trouble with a format pattern string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SimpleDateFormat ignoring month when parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056703/simpledateformat-ignoring-month-when-parsing). Or as you see it, possible duplicate of [Parsing a string to date format in java defaults date to 1 and month to January](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33427670/parsing-a-string-to-date-format-in-java-defaults-date-to-1-and-month-to-january).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse("2018-01-30T23:59:59.000");
    System.out.println(dateTime);
```

This prints:

> 2018-01-30T23:59:59

Your string is in ISO 8601 format. UTC or Coordinated Universal Time is not a format, it is a standard time used to define the time the rest of use in our respective time zones.

The date-time classes you were using, `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`, are long outdated and the former in particular notoriously troublesome. I recommend that you instead use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

A `LocalDateTime` is a date with time of day and without time zone or offset from UTC. Its one-argument `parse` method parses ISO 8601, which is why no explicit formatter is needed.

### What went wrong in your code

Your format pattern string has a number of issues to it. Which is one reason why you should appreciate the above solution without any explicit formatter. The first thing that goes wrong is: Your format pattern string has a colon, `:`, between seconds and milliseconds, whereas your date-time string has a dot, `.`. This is why you get the exception.

However, fixing this, your code yields the following `Date`:

> Sun Dec 31 23:00:00 CET 2017

It’s one month off from the expected, and the minutes and seconds are missing. Because:

- Uppercase `YYYY` is for week-based year and only useful with a week number. You need lowercase `yyyy` for year.
- Uppercase `DD` is for day of year. You need lowercase `dd` for day of month.
- You correctly used uppercase `MM` for month. Trying the same again for minutes won’t work. Maybe you can guess by now: it’s lowercase `mm`.
- Not surprising you need lowercase `ss` for seconds.
- Using`MS` for milliseconds is interesting. `SimpleDateFormat` takes it as `M` for month (which we’ve already had twice before) and uppercase `S` for millisecond. Instead you needed uppercase `SSS` for the three digits of milliseconds.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)
- [Wikipedia article: Coordinated Universal Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) on UTC

Answer (score 3):

See the doc of [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and try this:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
```

Comment: for minutes it should be "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSS", i dont know it is upvoted :), please correct it.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the literal `T`:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:SS");
```

See [This SO Answer for more examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138085/java-date-format-including-additional-characters)

Update: Your string is in the format

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS
```

but you are trying to parse it with a completely uppercase format string.

This does not do what you want it to do and you should [read the documentation on SimpleDateFormat and the format string placeholders](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)