# Getting issue with the formatter

Tags: java, date, time, timezone, datetime-format

I am trying

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd'T'hh:mm:ssZ").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime())
```

and the output which I am getting is `2018-16-11T07:16:48+0530`. But the expected one is `2018-16-11T07:16:48+05:30`.

Comment: Your date format string is wrong; use `MM` for months, not `mm`.

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Apart from that your problem is the opposite of this one: [Not able to understand “YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS” date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50271274/not-able-to-understand-yyyy-mm-ddthhmmss-date-format).

Comment: You expect `2018-16-11T07:16:48+05:30`?? What was that supposed to mean? The 11th day of the 16th month?? It looks like what you really want is ISO 8601 format. I suggest you can live with `OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata")).toString()` (substitute your time zone of choice). It gives a string like `2018-09-12T12:50:11.265+05:30`, that is, with milliseconds, even microseconds depending on what the platform supports. For most purposes this won’t pose a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use XXX instead of Z for timezone to get it in the format you want:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ssXXX");
```

Reference:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 1):

You should use like this..

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
```